# Form loses focus after clicking button

Tags: vb.net, forms

when clicking on the start button in the code below, the form seems to lose focus and I need to click the stop button twice to stop the count. (First click to activate the form, second to click the button)  Can someone please explain this behavior or offer a better alternative?

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim testrunning As Boolean

    Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
        testrunning = True
        test()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnStop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click
        testrunning = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub test()
        Dim count As Integer

        While testrunning = True
            count += 1
            TextBox1.Text = count.ToString
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form doesnt loose focus. The stop button does not gain focus after start-button is clicked- You could give it focus (btnStop.Focus()) in btnStart_Click.
The other problem is that you should change your test-function. It is more like a benchmark.
Read some articles about why using Application.DoEvents [could be dangerous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jfoscoding/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents) and is of [poor design](https://web.archive.org/web/20131212040731/http://www.codinghorror.com:80/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html) in general. It is better to use [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) or [BackgroundWorkers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=net-7.0) instead.
I think in your code the Application.DoEvents first only let the stop button gain focus and you need a second click to perform the click event.